# ReactJS - Passing function deeper

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

Do you know why, when I invoke function outside of map it works, but not inside?
I was trying to pass "this" in map's callback function argument. I trine to bind inline inside of map and nothing worked.

```
var React = require('react');
var PropTypes = require('prop-types');

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      events: props.events
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e){
    console.log("Boom!")
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table onClick={this.handleClick}><tbody>
        {this.props.events.map(function(event){
               return(
                   <tr key={event.position}>
                   <td onClick={this.handleClick}>{event.position}</td>
                   <td>{event.start_time}</td>
                   <td>{event.duration}</td>
                   <td>{event.end_time}</td>
                   <td>{event.text}</td>
                   </tr>
               ) 
            })}
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
module.exports = List;
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to a fat arrow function which makes `this` fall back to the outer scope. A `function` creates a new `this` when executed the way you're using it.

```
{this.props.events.map((event) => {
    ...
})}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. It works even without binding in the constructor.
I heard that fat arrow functions work differently. Is it possible to achieve the same not using it? I try to understand why binding didn't work this time. Trying to be clever one day :D

Comment: Yeah, that looks like making more sense than the things I tried to do. Thank You Bossman!